# Countdown counter in Hours

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to write code for a counter which countdown from 4 hours in hour, minute and second components (3:59:59 ... 3:59:58 ..... 0:0:1 ... 0:0:0) in which the user can increment or decrement any of those components by using +/-icons. I wrote a code but I cannot make it? How can I complete it? In my code just increase/decrease icon works.

```js
function increment() {
    hour = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("hour")[0].value);
    minute = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("minute")[0].value);
    second = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("second")[0].value);
    if (second + 1 == 61) {
        minute = minute + 1;
        if (minute == 61) {
            hour = hour + 1;
            if (hour == 3) {
                hour = 0;
            }
            minute = 0;
        }
        second = 0;
    } else {
        second += 1;
    }
    document.getElementsByName("hour")[0].value = hour.toString();
    document.getElementsByName("minute")[0].value = minute.toString();
    document.getElementsByName("second")[0].value = second.toString();
}

function decrement() {
    hour = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("hour")[0].value);
    minute = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("minute")[0].value);
    second = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("second")[0].value);
    if (second - 1 <= 0) {
        minute -= 1;
        if (minute <= 0) {
            hour -= 1;
            if (hour <= 0) {
                hour = 2;
                minute = 60;
            } else {
                minute = 60;
            }
        }
        second = 60;
    } else {
        second -= 1;
    }
    document.getElementsByName("hour")[0].value = hour.toString();
    document.getElementsByName("minute")[0].value = minute.toString();
    document.getElementsByName("second")[0].value = second.toString();
}
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Hour</td>
            <td>
               <input type="text" name = "hour" placeholder = "HOUR" value="0"/>
            </td>
            <td>Minute</td>
            <td>
               <input type="text" name="minute" placeholder="MINUTE" value="0"/>
            </td>
            <td>Second</td>
            <td>
               <input type="text" name="second" placeholder="SECOND" value="0"/>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><br>
               <input type="button" name="+" value="+" onclick= "return increment()"/>
            </td>
            <td><br>
               <input type="button" name="-" value="-" onclick="return decrement()"/>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just about everything in your code wreaks of 1997, it's hard to try to help you when really all the code should be reworked, including the HTML. `<table>` should not be used for layout purposes, only form elements that will be submitting data through a `form.submit()` should have a `name` attribute, `getElementsByName()` shouldn't be used and `querySelector()` should, inline event handling attributes, such as `onclick` should not be used and `addEventListener()` should. You should really learn about modern HTML and JavaScript that is used in this century.

Comment: Note: Use ` if(second+1==60)` instead 61 and minutes same otherwise you get 60 seconds/minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i would go about it, first of all, you had the script execute before the body which caused problems since the elements you were trying to select didn't exist yet,
also, you're trying to do everything everywhere, but if you keep state, it is much more manageable

```html
    <script>
      const maxTime = 4 * 60 * 60; // 4 hours in seconds
      const hours = document.querySelector("[name='hour']");
      const minutes = document.querySelector("[name='minute']");
      const seconds = document.querySelector("[name='second']");

      let remaining = maxTime;
      let counter = setInterval(decrement, 1000);

      function increment() {
        remaining = Math.max(maxTime, remaining + 1);
        display();
      }

      function decrement() {
        remaining = Math.max(0, remaining - 1);
        display();
      }
      function display() {
        const time = new Date(remaining * 1000).toISOString();

        hours.value = time.slice(11, 13);
        minutes.value = time.slice(14, 16);
        seconds.value = time.slice(17, 19);
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setInterval`  function
This will call your decrement function every second

```js
setInterval(decrement, 1000)
```

The first parameter is the function to be executed.
The second parameter indicates the number of milliseconds before execution.